# Easy to use program to calculate the HOMFLY polynomial of a braid word?

Tags: reference-request, knot-theory, braid-groups

Easy to use program to calculate the HOMFLY polynomial of a braid word?

Looking for a reference. Thanks!

Comment: I think I've heard that people use this: http://www.layer8.co.uk/maths/braids/.  I don't use it enough to be certain, but the KnotTheory Mathematica package I think lets you enter knots by braid closures, and it has the HOMFLY polynomial: http://katlas.org/wiki/The_HOMFLY-PT_Polynomial.  (I also have a Mathematica package for calculating HOMFLY polynomials of tangles, and it's not too hard to use it for braid words, but I don't think the program has been tested nearly enough to trust it: https://github.com/kmill/planalg/blob/master/Planalg/HOMFLYPT.wl -- there are examples in the folder)

Comment: @KyleMiller I downloaded and installed the first programmed you mentioned. It's great! Thanks! However, when I ask it to calculate the HOMFLY of the braid word $s1-s1-s1$ it tells me it's $1$, where according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trefoil_knot it should be $-a^4+a^2z^2+2a^2$. Any idea what's going on here?